# Button command is passing two positional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm developing a GUI for a desktop app and I'm kind of new to OOP. I have the following piece of code:

```
class Frontpage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        .
        .
        .
        self.db_table = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, container.table_opt, *container.tables_list, command=self.update_tree)


    def update_tree(self):
        pass
```

I can´t seem to call this method whenever the option menu is pressed because I get the following error:

TypeError: update_tree() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I suppose that this is because the method is receiving both the tk.OptionMenu and the Frontpage object. What can I do so that it only gives the Frontpage object?

Comment: Just add another parameter to the `update_tree()` method, and ignore it.  You cannot change what parameters Tkinter provides when calling it.

Comment: The option is sending the caption of the selected option, so add the parameter `option_name` to `update_tree` and use it to identify what option was selected.

Answer (score 0):

The other parameter passed to the `update_tree` method is the name of the new option that was just selected.

To fix the issue, add an unused parameter to your `update_tree` method like this:

```py
def update_tree(self, _new_value):
    pass
```

Or if you want to be able to call the `update_tree` method from somewhere else in your code without having to pass an extra argument that will be unused anyway, you can make the extra argument optional like this:

```py
def update_tree(self, _new_value=None):
    pass
```

This way, you can do call it from the class like `self.update_tree()` and it will also work with tkinter.